# "Microsoft Word" entry in Save As dialog's navigation pane?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When you open the "Save As" or "Open" dialog in Microsoft Word, there is an entry in the pane on the left labeled "Microsoft Word" (pictured below).  What is this for?

[image]

If you click on it and try to save a file to that location, an error message appears that reads, "You can't save here. Please choose another location."

Clicking on it just displays an empty file list.  Expanding it by clicking on the little triangle yields no sub-entries.

Every Microsoft Office app has something like this (e.g. Excel has a "Microsoft Excel" item).

I'm using Microsoft Word 2016, but I have also seen this in 2010.

This question has been cross-posted on the [Microsoft Community forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/purpose-of-microsoft-word-entry-in-save-as-dialogs/8eb2d7a2-2634-474c-be3c-576df6bfe449?tm=1506455832358).

Comment: Interesting. I have it too. Also for Excel. So in a way it is a way to identify what program you're using. But I suspect this location is used in case Word or excel crashed, and you have unsaved documents. I bet they will appear here. Interestingly enough, if you right-click that folder and choose: open in new window, the location does not appear to exist.

Comment: @LPChip I forcefully quit Word by ending its task in Task Manager to see if the unsaved files appear in this location.  They do not.

Comment: Hmm, even more interesting. I honestly have no idea.

Comment: I believe it's part of the forced Windows-OneDrive-Office integration you can't get rid of. Try quiting onedrive and ending Office tasks in task manager.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBerbec.  It only appears in the "Save As" and "Open" dialogs of Microsoft Word.  It does not appear in a regular File Explorer window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be holding shortcuts to special folders, such as Templates, in one central location under Office's folder in the AppData folder (as far as I remember, that was in 2010). Now (2016 edition) when you choose to save a file as a template, a special location under your user's folder will open automatically for you to save there.

In this screenshots from [this web page](http://www.speakeasysolutions.com/blog/2009/11/26/modifying-word-2007-normal-dotm-template/), notice the templates shortcut under Microsoft Office Word, 2010 edition.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sanny.  Any idea why it's still there in 2016?

Comment: Probably OS differences. If you have Windows 10 like I do, custom templates will be stored under the documents folder, older Windows may still store under the AppData folder. If my guess was not true then expect this entry to be removed in future editions.

Answer (score 0):

It's also used for mapping folder locations for users.

By registry (where XX is office version e.g. 15 for 2013):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\XX.0\common\open find\adminaddedplaces

Key names: Place0 through Place9
String name: name
Data value: enter the desired display name

String name: path
Data value: folder path
```

Via group policy (with templates for Office):

```
User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office [version] > File Open/Save Dialog > Places Bar Locations.
```

Source: https://www.poremsky.com/office/using-the-places-bar-in-office-2013/

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jon.  I tried the registry method and it didn't work for me (see this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/gHazcKS.png).  Do you see anything wrong?  I set the version to "16.0" because I'm running Office 2016 (actually, I have Office 365).  Maybe that is not the correct version number?  Maybe it doesn't work with Office 2016?  Rebooting after making the registry change didn't help either.

Comment: The path looks ok to me. I've just tested with Office 2016 Pro Plus on a server and that worked. When I tried with my local Office 365 (2016), I noticed that there was already a version 15.0 key but not one for 16.0, so I had to manually create that to get it to work. Maybe if yours was originally a 2013 version that later got updated then it will still be using the 15.0 registry key?

Comment: Nope, my computer came with 2016 pre-installed which I later activated after buying a subscription.  I'm using Windows Home edition...maybe it only works on other editions?  I'll have to try it at work sometime.